# How can I test in bash if an EBS volume already has a filesystem on it?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, filesystems

I am attaching an existing EBS volume to my new EC2 instance. But I don't know if the volume already has a file system type already.

When I try to `mount` it I get the error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvd...
```

I would have to run `mkfs` in order to initialise the file system:

```
mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdi
```

but I don't want to run this if the file system is already initialised. (I might break things creating an `ex4` when an `ext3` was already there)

So I need a way to read the file system type before mounting a volume, how can I do that?

The only thing that come to mind is to `mount` the volume and wait for the error mentioned in the beginning.

```
mount /dev/xvd... /my/volume/path
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `blkid -o value -s TYPE /dev/xvd` to determine the filesystem on an unmounted device. Easier than parsing `file -s /dev/xvd`.